# How to wait for all scripts loading when using $.load()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

In jquery, if I have

```
$("#box").load("blah.html", function() { 
    alert(1); 
});
```

and the html file has some script import tags, how can I ensure the callback function (that alerts 1) gets called after all the scripts load in the html file?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want alert(1) to be called after everything is loaded? Isn't this what .load() already does?

Comment: @Tenza No, because if there is a script that will continue to run in the background......

Answer (score -1):

In the function parameter of .load() you'll need to include some parameters to handle the success or failure of the load.

```
$("#box").load("blah.html", function(response,status,xhttp) { 
    if(status == "success")
        //success handling/loading
    if(status == "error")
        //error handling
});
```

Hope this helps. W3 schools has a good demo on jQuery's .load() functionality if you're still having issues.